# Reporting services - subscribe to all reports in folder

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a number of reports in a folder, and it will grow in a time. To subscribe to all reports user has to go to each one and create subscription. With about 10 reports it's manageable, but when there are 30 reports and a new user should be added to a subscription it's becoming difficult.

How can I create some kind of batch subscription? I mean - to make easy subscription to all reports in a folder and send it to the user(s) (no matter where - e-mail or file share). Is there some administrative option or should I write some script to achive it?

Environment: SQL Server 2008 R2 + SSRS 2008 R2 (Standard Edition) on W2K8 R2 (Enterprise Edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution following [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/7cc7d5ec-c549-4944-8c5b-70c0a940978b) where `rs.exe` is used. Esentially it's example [from BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.createsubscription.aspx#Y1596). I've changed it to suit my needs and it works. Usage:

```
rs.exe -i CreateSubscriptionTest.rss -s http://myreportserveraddresshere/reportserver

' CreateSubscriptionTest.rss
Public Sub Main()
    rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim desc As String        = "Report description"
    Dim eventType As String   = "TimedSubscription"
    Dim scheduleXml As String = "<ScheduleDefinition><StartDateTime>2012-03-22T09:30:00</StartDateTime><WeeklyRecurrence><WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval><DaysOfWeek><Thursday>True</Thursday></DaysOfWeek></WeeklyRecurrence></ScheduleDefinition>"

    Dim extensionParams(7) As ParameterValue

    extensionParams(0)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(0).Name  = "TO"
    extensionParams(0).Value = "my.address@email.com"

    extensionParams(1)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(1).Name  = "ReplyTo"
    extensionParams(1).Value = "admin@email.com"

    extensionParams(2)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(2).Name  = "IncludeReport"
    extensionParams(2).Value = "True"

    extensionParams(3)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(3).Name  = "RenderFormat"
    extensionParams(3).Value = "MHTML"

    extensionParams(4)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(4).Name  = "Subject"
    extensionParams(4).Value = "@ReportName was executed at @ExecutionTime"

    extensionParams(5)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(5).Name  = "Comment"
    extensionParams(5).Value = "Some HTML code inside email's body<br><br>Go!"

    extensionParams(6)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(6).Name  = "IncludeLink"
    extensionParams(6).Value = "True"

    extensionParams(7)       = New ParameterValue()
    extensionParams(7).Name  = "Priority"
    extensionParams(7).Value = "NORMAL"

    Dim parameters() As ParameterValue

    ' If you need setup parameters

    'Dim parameter As New ParameterValue()
    'parameter.Name = "EmpID"
    'parameter.Value = "288"
    'parameters(0) = parameter

    'parameter.Name = "ReportMonth"
    'parameter.Value = "12"
    'parameters(1) = parameter

    'parameter.Name = "ReportYear"
    'parameter.Value = "2003"
    'parameters(2) = parameter

    Dim matchData As String = scheduleXml

    Dim extSettings As New ExtensionSettings()
    extSettings.ParameterValues = extensionParams
    extSettings.Extension       = "Report Server Email"

    Dim returnValue As String

    Dim reports() As String = { _ 
        "/MyReports/Executive/SalesYear", _ 
        "/MyReports/Executive/SalesMonth", _ 
        "/MyReports/Executive/SalesWeek"}

    For Each report As String In reports
        returnValue = rs.CreateSubscription(report, extSettings, desc, eventType, matchData, parameters)
        Console.WriteLine(returnValue)
    Next

End Sub 'Main
```

The key part is to define `reports()` variable with report names. Name is the full report path.

The above example creates new schedule for each subscription. It's getting very messy in SQL Server Agent with a lot of reports schedules, so I changed it to use **shared schedule**. The difference is in `scheduleXml` declaration - you use schedule ID instead of XML string:

```
Dim scheduleXml As String = "924b9bb6-2340-4f5c-a897-465af7ff310e"
```

How can you obtain the schedule ID:

```
-- using T-SQL
SELECT
    ScheduleID,
    Name
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Schedule
WHERE
    EventType = 'SharedSchedule'

' using rss file: GetSchedulers.rss
' run with rs.exe -i GetSchedulers.rss -s http://myreportserveraddresshere/reportserver

Public Sub Main()
    rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim returnValue As Schedule()

    returnValue = rs.ListSchedules()

    For Each sch As Schedule In returnValue
        Console.WriteLine(sch.ScheduleID & " - " & sch.name)
    Next

End Sub 'Main
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to send a subscription to all reports users by e-mail is to set up the subscription on an e-mail group, and add (and remove) users from that e-mail group as desired.

The simplest way to send a subscription to all reports users by file share is to set up the subscription on a file share, and grant (and remove) access to that file share as desired.

I don't know of any way to set up the equivalent of a batch subscription. However, it should be possible to write a stored procedure to update existing schedules or create new schedules in the ReportServer database, based on a user ID passed to the query as a parameter.

You can see examples of queries that access the subscription tables on the ReportServer database [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deanka/archive/2009/01/13/diagnosing-and-troubleshooting-subscriptions.aspx).

Comment: I have no option (yet) to manage e-mail groups. The ReportServer database operations look promising. I'll give it a try.